# Create a Calculated Member to remove need to load pre calculated measure

Tags: ssas

I am trying to replicate the following sql statement into MDX so that I can create a calculated member in the cube using the base loaded members instead of having to calculate it outside the cube in the table and then loading it

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ((A.SALES_TYPE_CD = 1) AND (A.REG_SALES=0)) 
     THEN A.WIN_SALES
     ELSE 0 
END) AS Z_SALES
```

I am currently loading `SALES_TYPE_CD` as a dimension and `REG_SALES` and `WIN_SALES` as measures.
I also have a few other dimensions in the cube but for simplicity, lets just say I have 2 other dimensions, `LOCATION` and `ITEM`
The dimension has `LOCATION` has 3 levels, `"Region"->"District"->"Store"`, ordered from top to bottom level.
The dimension has `ITEM` has 3 levels, `"CLASS"->"SUBCLASS"->"SKU"`, ordered from top to bottom level.
The dimension has `SALES TYPE` has 2 levels, `"SALES_TYPE_GROUP"->"SALES_TYPE_CD"`, ordered from top to bottom level.
I know that I cannot create a simple calculated member in the cube which crossjoins the "SALES_TYPE" dimension with another dimension to get the answer I want.
I would think that it would be a more complicated MDX statement something like :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Z_Sales]
 AS 'sum(filter(crossjoin(leaves(), [Sales Type].[Sales Type].
[Sales_Type_CD].&[1]), [Measures].[REG_SALES]=0),[Measures].
[WIN_SALES])', 
FORMAT_STRING = '#,#', 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

But this does not seem to return the desired result.
What would be the proper MDX code to generate the desired result?

Comment: What's wrong with the result your current query returns?

Comment: The REG_SALES=0 filter needs to be evaluated at the fact row grain right (rather than aggregating up to a product subtotal for a month then checking whether the subtotal is 0)? In that case if you will make REG_SALES a degenerate dimension you can do this efficiently in MDX. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna say, I know there's the FILTER() function, but you will make your life a lot easier if you add a dimension on Reg_Sales.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of testing with the data and I now know that there is no way I can get the right answer by using MDX alone in this scenario. Like "Greg" and "Tab" suggested, the only way would be to have reg sales as a dimension. Since this is a measure, that is out of the question because of the large number of possibilities for the value which has a data type of decimal (18,2)
Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.